# Не работает условие? PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, if, условия

Почему не срабатывает условие? По факту, получается - если 403 != 403 то 
    присваиваем true. Очевидно, что здесь условие не работает, но оно, все равно, присваивает true. Что я не так понимаю?

```
$headers = 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden';
preg_match('/[0-9]{3}/ui', $headers, $matches);
if((int)$matches[0] != 403) {
    $headers_check = true;
}
echo $headers_check;
//Результат вывода 1
```

Comment: Где у вас `$headers_check` объявлен? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dcf962e514c3ed48d4d7e72aa91b8f42a77220c3

Comment: Точняк, забыл, что нужно инициализировать переменные! Спасибо за наводку! Вопрос решен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё у вас работает правильно, допишите `else $headers_check = false` и выведите переменную через `var_dump` и увидите корректную обработку условия.

```php
$headers = 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden';
preg_match('/[0-9]{3}/ui', $headers, $matches);
if((int)$matches[0] != 403) {
  $headers_check = true;
} else {
  $headers_check = false;
}
var_dump($headers_check);
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что переменные нужно определять полностью

```
$headers = 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden';
preg_match('/[0-9]{3}/ui', $headers, $matches);
if((int)$matches[0] != 403) {
    $headers_check = true;
} else
    $headers_check = false;
var_dump($headers_check);
```

Особенно, если вы используете их в коде повторно.

А еще лучше так

```
$headers = 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden';
preg_match('/[0-9]{3}/ui', $headers, $matches);
$headers_check = ((int)$matches[0] != 403);
var_dump($headers_check);
```

Comment: Такое  $headers_check = ((int)$matches[0] != 403); я еще не пробовал использовать, спасибо!

Comment: @unreal_serg Отметьте один из продложеных ответов как верный

Answer (score -1):

Перед условием инициализируй переменную.

```
$headers_check = false;
```